# How to write update query in Hibernate for where clause i am using foreign key column?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

when i write update query in hibernate. i am getting this error. I am using Hibernate 3.2 with MySQL 5.0.Here in UserDetails.java, Login is forign key referencing to primary key (loginId) of Login.java .

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.BinaryLogicOperatorNode.extractDataType(BinaryLogicOperatorNode.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.BinaryLogicOperatorNode.initialize(BinaryLogicOperatorNode.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.prepareLogicOperator(HqlSqlWalker.java:1007)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3992)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1762)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
```

Here  is Service class

```
 Date birthDay = formatter1.parse(brthDay);
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Login login = (Login) session.get(Login.class, loginId);
        Query query2 = session.createQuery("update UserDetails set name=:Name, secEmailId=:SecEmailId, dob=:DOB, gender=:Gender  where Login=:LoginId");
        query2.setString("Name", name);
        query2.setString("SecEmailId", secEmailId);
        query2.setDate("DOB", birthDay);
        query2.setString("Gender", gender);
        query2.setParameter("LoginId", login);
        profileUpdated = query2.executeUpdate();
```

Here is UserDetails.java pojo class

```
private Long udid;
private Login login;
private String name;
private String secEmailId;
private Date dob;
private String gender;
private long createrId;
private Date createdDate;
private long updaterId;
private Date updatedDate;
settes & getters
```

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You only have Login object in your Entity. Calling a foreign key must be an (Integer or int) to put in HQL. And you cannot call a foreign key as login.getId() because hibernate doesn't allow to use brackets in HQL. The purpose of using Integer is so that it can be set to null.

```
private Login login;
```

You have to reference to your Entity but don't want to load it from the database and just to get the foreign key, use this approach. But you need to add "insertable"=false and "updatable"=false in @Column attribute to prevent losing the correct reference to an entity. Perhaps, this is your UserDetails class.

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

    //Other attributes, id, phNo, address, etc..

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) //Relationship is up to you.
    @JoinColumn(name = "login_id")
    private Login login; //This is object.

    @Column(name = "login_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer fkLoginId; //Here is your foreign key.

    //getter and setters.
}
```

This won't generate another column in database because it cannot be inserted or updated and it just referenced to a column. After that, you got fkLoginId as a foreign key and update your UserDetails using HQL like this.

```
String name = "Updated Name";
int id = 1;

session = HibernateUtil.getSession(); //Consider declared
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
Login login = (Login) session.get(Login.class, loginId);
String hql = "update UserDetails set name=:Name where fkLoginId=:Id"; //<---Ans
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("Name", name);
query.setParameter("Id", id);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

Hope it helps.